# .srt file types doesn't exist under 'Choose default apps by file type' after after formatting windows 10, what to do?

Tags: windows

Before I did a clean install of my desktop with windows 10 I had .srt to open by default in Sublime Text after I have formatted my computer I somehow miss the file format .srt under 'Choose default apps by file type'.

The .srt should be be between the .srf and .srw file types, but it isn't (as shown in the image here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop-winpc/srt-files-back-to-unknown-application/e33cace8-dd59-4557-9631-e8e82a8307b3?auth=1).

If I try "open with and find Sublime (or any other software for that matter, it will open it, but it will not set it as the default program even though I checked the box) and will still appear as an unknown filetype....

If I go into properties and try to change the "open with" from there, it will just keep showing "choose a program" even still.

tried updating the computer and restart it and frankly I've given up, and it doesn't seem anyone have run into this problem before of missing a filetype under 'Choose default apps by file type'.

I also tried
1) Settings - Indexing Options
2) Advanced button
3) File Types tab
4) Add New Extension to List box, type in extension (without a period) such as "py"
5) Click Add, OK and Close

and while the format does appear in the 'Choose default apps by file type', it still doesn't let me change it at all...

Anyone got an answer to this problem?

---

I have now tried to go into regedit and use "search" on anything that included "sublime" and ".srt" and deleted them all... restarted the computer, reinstall sublime. The file extension I created myself in the indexing option, has been deleted.

Sublime can still open the file, but if you try to make it default program by simply opening it or or going into the files properties and do it that way, it will just open the file without it making it the default program as it should.

going into the indexing option and create the .srt extension format so it can be found under 'Choose default apps by file type' will allow you to choose notepad or wordpad as default program. When I choose either of them, the will just freeze for 1-2 sec and then nothing has changed and the extension havn't been associated with any of the programs.

I tried following the following links, and nothing has worked. Guess I'll just have to accept there is no solution rather than to live with out until I reform my PC again, cause it works without a problem on my laptop and I formatted them both the same time and installed the exact same things on both and the exact same way s:

I've tried to use the following links for help, but to no avail since non of the things I have tried have fixed it.

https://superuser.com/questions/655600/i-cant-set-a-program-as-the-default-to-open-a-filetype-with-in-windows-7
https://superuser.com/questions/91655/open-with-dialog-ignores-my-selection
https://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows
[Windows 7 file extension association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620764/windows-7-file-extension-association/34096294)

Comment: Don't you get the option to set this up if you double-click on an .srt file in explorer?

Comment: @Rup
when I am under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT it got a folder with a file in it and a sub folder called 'PersistentHandler' with two files in it

I don't know if this is a folder I created when I made the extension in the 5 steps I wrote I've tried, or if it was there has always been there (so I dear not delete it since I'm not THAT techsavy and have no idea what I'm doing right now)

Comment: the file in the .srt folder says        
name: (Standart)  type: REG_SZ  Data: (value undefined)

the two files in the PersistentHandler folder inside the .srt folder says
name: (Standart)  type: REG_SZ  Data: {5E941D80-BF96-11CD-B579-08002B30BFEB}

name: (OriginalPersistentHandler)  type: REG_SZ  Data: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

so what to do from here??

Comment: Oh :-/ Then I'd expect it to work, sorry. I'm not sure why this isn't appearing in control panel for you then.

Comment: Well the biggest problem is I can't see if this is a folder that has just come from the  making an .srt extension under the indexing option :/ and i'm afraid I destroy something if i delete the folder just to make a new .srt folder and sadly it's not possible to see date/time on it

Answer (score 1):

One way to get an empty .srt entry back in the 'Choose default apps by file type' control panel is to create a new key for .srt in your registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT:

1. Open Registry Editor, e.g. by typing 'regedit' into the start menu or a command prompt
2. At the top of the tree, right-click on 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT', New -> Key
3. Rename the new key to '.srt' and press enter to save