# Use List of Windows accounts to add reg keys using SIDS

Tags: batch-file, wmic

## edit re explanation to improve answers.

**Project**

As a third party engineer I am attending a site to install a piece of Software. The Infrastructure is "very" locked down. I will be supplied with an admin account for the day to install the software. However, to make the software work properly FOR ALL USERS (not just admin logged in) I have been instructed by IT dept. to manually create a KEY and then add a string value within created key for every user account on the PC. Our software in a standard environment caters for this with an all users reg key but it doesn't run (not allowed - don't ask!) in these specific places.

The location of where they want the the KEY is within the HKEY_USERS path in the reg:-

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX\Software\Microsoft\

so lets say 2 people logged in this PC and they need to use our software later on

john.jones

mary.shelley

I need to find the sid relating to john jones and go and add the key to his section in HKEY_USERS

I then need to find mary.shelley sid and then go and the key to her HKEY_USERS section, etc.

Now I know from the environments I work in there could be 20 + user acounts on there so really would like to avoid manually adding they keys over and over for all the accounts on every PC I'm installing at.

A log on script would be better, but this all I have to deal with at present.

**State of Script Now**

```
@echo off
REM Read file with user names
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in ("users.txt") do (
    REM use user name to find SID
    FOR /F "delims=" %%H IN ('"wmic useraccount where name='%%~G' get sid| findstr /vi "SID""') DO (
        REM Strip trailing line with CR
        FOR /F "delims= " %%I IN ("%%~H") DO (
            REM %%I is now the SID of the USER
            REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\%%I\Software\Microsoft\addstuffhere" /f
            REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\%%I\Software\Microsoft\addstuffhere" /t REG_SZ /d "addstuffhere"" /f
        )
    )
)
```

This is pretty much automating the whole thing as planned; loops through a text file of user names of users who use the PC, grabs the SID, applies sid as variable, then is used to write the key in the right place for that user, and on through the list doing to same for every account listed.

The only part that may need altering is the WMIC section is not finding certain users who have bona fide windows accounts.

when I tested the working code on my laptop it worked fine for my administrator account, but me logged in as joe_blogs (e.g.) came up with "no instance available". Because in isolation the WMIC code just brought up only a few not all, so couldn't do what it needed to do.

I know from previous questions this WMIC code brings up every account:-

```
WMIC Path Win32_UserProfile Where "Special='False' And Not LocalPath='Null'" Get LocalPath,SID | find /v ""
```

Perhaps that can be incorporated into current working code to make sure every account is catered for.

I know the users all need to have logged in at each PC for this to work, so with regards to the list of user profiles, I can garner that on the day asking "who of your users needs to use our stuff on the PC's" and make the users.txt

thanks  - hope that really explains it :/

## edit instructions for what I have been asked to do (altered key names slightly for privacy)

```
1. Log on to the PC with a standard technician admin account
2. Open regedit.exe
3. Navigate to* HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-     XXXXX\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Addins\
a. Right-click Addins > New > Key and create foo
b. Right-click foo > New > String Value and create Name
c. Double-click Name and in Value Data enter† C:\foo\file\foo.dll
4. Repeat step 3 for each user: it should be possible to edit the SID in an exported key by right-clicking on the next 
HKEY_USERS entry > Rename > Ctrl+C > Esc then replacing the SID in the exported reg key – this has not been tested but may be worth trying

*The user SID is unique so this has to be done per user. If there are a lot of users listed in the registry it is possible to find which SID belongs to which user by checking the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

Comment: You have to use a `FOR /F` command to retrieve the `WMIC` output.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I’m having is isolating the actual Sid for the user in the text file?

Comment: Your input file example does not show the SIDS with the usernames.  How is anyone supposed to know what format it is in?  Why are you using WMIC if you already have the username and SID?

Comment: That’s the point, I don’t know the Sid, it’s a standard notepad text file Utf-8, so I want to match the user name in the text file against the output of WMIC command , get the Sid for that user, then write a reg key against the users Sid ID in hkey users

Comment: You are really confusing the hell out of me.  I am looking at your previous questions about this same topic and you seem to have all the information you need in your previous questions.

Comment: Just be clear script will loop in turn through the text file , for say John.jones it’s gets his Sid, assigns as a variable, then writes reg key . Then for Mary etc etc

Comment: Can you please properly explain the task, because you appear to be going about it the wrong way. Are you trying to affect the registries of every local user, on a PC? Are you aware that only users who have logged in, and have not yet logged out will have their HKU keys available for modification? What you'd need to do is twofold, add to the available HKU entries, then find all logged out users, load their individual hives one by one, modify the keys and unload the hives again. You may find it easier to add the information to their registry, using a logon script instead.

Comment: Your opening paragraph is a little confusing too; it states, `I want to be able to have a txt file listing a set of windows users profiles`. Can you clarify if you have that file already propagated with the target user names or not?

Comment: You've edited your question again yet my questions remain unanswered. Do you have a list of all users for whom you wish to make registry changes or not? Do you understand that only users who have not yet logged out will have registries loaded under HKU? Can you explain a little more about why your software installation does not make all the required changes, and what exactly your additional changes are. I ask because I do not believe that you are going about this task in standard fashion.

Comment: I will either ask the names and create a list or if the customer do every one, either way I'm making a text file of user profile names before I run the main scripts. I have been able to run the reg key element on none logged in users and it writes the key. Still there after a reboot.

Comment: The problem is with your methodology, it is possible to answer your question, but as your methodology does not do what you require of it, answering the question seems pointless at this time. Unless you can expand upon the entire task, which it appears you do not know enough about, we cannot really help. Can you at least explain what the registry entries are that you're wanting to add, and why the software installation does not create them. Why does using `HKLM` not satisfy the requirements?

Comment: I am just telling my situation, at this site you need to add the manually in hkey users which you can only identify via the sid. I know everything about my job thanks, just this side of things is a rougue step. I think I'll leave it here, have enough to get it done quicker than manual entries, thanks for all the help! Cheers

Comment: You state that you know everything about your job, but both myself and @eryksun, have informed you that only logged in users keys are available under the HKU keys you're wanting to add to. All other users keys cannot be modified without individually loading their hives. You seem to be contradicting what we have stated, so unless you accept that your methodology may be wrong, or can show us that we're wrong, your task may remain unsolved.

Comment: I know what your saying but I'm just telling you what I have been instructed to do, I will edit the question with the exact instructions from the IT dept. It doesn't say anything about loading each user hive, just, as stated, logging in as admin and adding for the all the users etc.Thanks

Comment: The instructions you've now added do not mention a script, but also seems to be misguided. If the job was given to me, I would question the IT department, with regards not logged in users, etc. Let's be honest, anyone can follow a series of listed steps, if they require a third party to be doing this, it suggests that they're not the experts, they expect you to be. I believe their instructions are not capable of doing what I think they require.

Comment: I've been putting a script together to automate the process that's all. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your edit, it sounds like there's some room to wiggle here.  If we take 2 small liberties, this could be done in a single command line.  If one or both liberties can't be taken, let me know.

If WMIC isn't required, and if we can target all SIDs present rather than trying to match names to SIDs, then 'reg.exe' and 'for' can do this quickly.  Here's an example with sample output:

(Optional) Enum Profiles:

```
cmd:
for /f "delims=\ tokens=2" %A in ('reg query hku ^| findstr /i "S-1-5-21-" ^| findstr /v /i "_Classes"') do @echo ;[i] Profile Found: {%A}

output:
;[i] Profile Found: {S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1001}
;[i] Profile Found: {S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1002}
;[i] Profile Found: {S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1007}
```

Add Key+Value

```
cmd:
for /f "delims=\ tokens=2" %A in ('reg query hku ^| findstr /i "S-1-5-21-" ^| findstr /v /i "_Classes"') do @(reg add "hku\%A\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Addins\FooKey" /v FooName /t REG_SZ /d "C:\foo\file\foo.dll" /f >nul 2>&1 && (echo ;[i] Reg Key Added {%A}) || (echo ;[i] Reg Key Failed To Add {%A}))

output:
;[i] Reg Key Added {S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1001}
;[i] Reg Key Added {S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1002}
;[i] Reg Key Added {S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1007}
```

(Optional) Verify Success:

```
cmd:
for /f "delims=\ tokens=2" %A in ('reg query hku ^| findstr /i "S-1-5-21-" ^| findstr /v /i "_Classes"') do @(reg query "hku\%A\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Addins\FooKey" /v FooName 2>nul || echo ;[e] Couldn't Find Key {%A})

output:
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1001\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Addins\FooKey
    FooName    REG_SZ    C:\foo\file\foo.dll


HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1002\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Addins\FooKey
    FooName    REG_SZ    C:\foo\file\foo.dll


HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-277974881-2357464463-7727422770-1007\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Addins\FooKey
    FooName    REG_SZ    C:\foo\file\foo.dll
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, looks good! I tried the first line as bat file, didn’t run, then in cmd window, {%A} was unexpected at this time, also if possible a quick run through of how the delims/tokens part works, always struggle getting head round that :-)

Comment: Made the %A %%A and it worked! For enum, so the S-1-5-21 part in the key is that always given to actual user accounts ? Thanks !

Comment: Yes, "S-1-5-21" means user account.  The next 3 parts are the domain (which is either an AD domain, or the local "domain (aka, local computer), followed by the last part which is RID (aka sequential number of creation)).

Comment: Did that answer everything for you?  :-)

Comment: As for delims/tokens, the "delims" is where to chop the line.  In this example, I wanted to chop the line between back slashes ("\").  The "tokens" is which of the chopped parts you want back.  Since you didn't want "HKEY_USERS", I only asked for the 2nd token back, which of course was the SID.

Comment: great so token 3 would have been "software" - I like this -  full marks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding your question. My first comment should have made it quite clear.  You need to use a `FOR /F` command to capture the `WMIC` output.  That is the only way you can assign the SID to a variable.

```
@echo off
REM Read file with user names
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in ("users.txt") do (
    REM use user name to find SID
    FOR /F "delims=" %%H IN ('"wmic useraccount where name='%%~G' get sid| findstr /vi "SID""') DO (
        REM Strip trailing line with CR
        FOR /F "delims= " %%I IN ("%%~H") DO (
            REM %%I is now the SID of the USER
            REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\%%I\Software\Microsoft\addstuffhere" /f
            REG ADD "HKEY_USERS\%%I\Software\Microsoft\addstuffhere" /t REG_SZ /d "addstuffhere"" /f
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: That's exactly it, sorry for confusing you, I have tested and almost there the sid get extracted perfect but fails in the reg part, if I echo the variable to a text file seems there is some trailing spaces also meaning the reg part fails because it thinks the SID is wrong with the spaces at the back

Comment: Wow, smashed it, that works, for some reason for Administrator account of the test machines works amazing, but for me logged on it says there is no instance available, might need to tweak WMIC to show all accounts, sorry to be a pain...appreciate this....

Comment: Piping from wmic.exe is far from ideal since it's hard coded to write OEM encoded text. Make sure the console codepage is set to whatever the OEM codepage is in order to avoid mojibake. But give up all hope if you have user names and profile paths with arbitrary Unicode characters. There's no way to handle that with a legacy codepage, unless you're running Windows 10 with the beta support enabled to set OEM/ANSI to UTF-8.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised that the profile is loaded for every name in your list. Normally it's only loaded for an interactive session, and eventually gets unloaded when then user logs off. I 'd expect that you'd have to manually load some of the ntuser.dat hive files to a temporary key.

Comment: maybe better to get SIDS from here:- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList